# How to avoid stat_summary changing the y-axis range?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a chart setup the way I want with this code as an example.

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2019-04-01"), as.Date("2019-04-30"), "days")
fastTimes <- seq(40, 60, 1)
slowTimes <- seq(55, 75, 1)
times <- c(fastTimes, slowTimes)

nBob <- 500
nJane <- 1500
n <- nBob + nJane
cNames <- c(rep("Bob", nBob), rep("Jane", nJane))
cDates <- sample(dates, n, replace = TRUE)
cTimes <- sample(times, n, replace = TRUE)


df <- data.frame(cNames, cDates, cTimes)

mapping <- aes(x = cNames, y = cTimes)
ggplot(df, mapping) + geom_violin(scale = "area") + coord_flip()
```

I would like to add a label to each violin with the sample count.  I have updated the full plot call as follows and it creates the label I want in the location I want.  But it shifts the y-axis min/max to include the sample count.  i.e., it changes to run from 0 to 1500 instead of from 40 to 80.

```
ggplot(df, mapping) + geom_violin(scale = "area") + coord_flip() +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, fun.max = length, geom = "text", aes(label = ..ymax..), color = "black",  vjust = -1)
```

How can I add the label without changing the y-axis scaling?

Thanks

EDIT:  This is what it looks like once I add the stat_summary call.

[image]

Comment: On my r session, I don't have this issue. Can you post an image of the plot you get ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that when you are calling `fun.max` in `stat_summary` function it extends the plot to this particular y value.

Instead of using `stat_summary`, you can use `geom_text` and calculate the length of each group (and set their x, y positions) on the fly by using `dplyr` package such as:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = cNames, y = cTimes))+
  geom_violin(scale = "area")+
  geom_text(inherit.aes = FALSE, 
            data = df %>% group_by(cNames) %>% summarise(Nb = n(), Mean = mean(cTimes)), 
            aes(x = cNames, y = Mean, label = Nb), color = "black", vjust = -1)+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: FWIW, regarding fun.max vs fun.ymas, I read on https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_summary.html to replace their use:

fun.ymin, fun.y, fun.ymax  Deprecated, use the versions specified above instead.

I'll test out your solution later today.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jobu, indeed you totally right, I did not see this part about the deprecated versions. My apologies. Let me know if my answer works for you.

Comment: Yes that works.   I'm accepting the answer.  Thanks.